# Eclipse RCP Fragment How to Build library.jar

Tags: maven, build, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a plug-in fragment which contributes a jar file to the host plug-in, following [these instructions](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Steps_to_use_Fragments_to_patch_a_plug-in). It works by creating a file `library.jar` which is specified in `build.properties` and associated with a directory which contains the source to be built.

It all works as expected, except I can't figure out how to cause `library.jar` to be created in Eclipse. When I run a Maven build that points to my fragment project and includes it as a module, the file `library.jar` shows up in the project directory. But building or cleaning the project in eclipse does not create the file.

I want other developers to be able to generate `library.jar` in their Eclipse workspace without running the Maven build. I'm really surprised that the Maven build creates `libary.jar` in the plug-in project itself, and not just in the product created in the build target. There should be a way to get Eclipse to do this without running the Maven build.

EDIT:

build.properties:

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               library.jar
source.library.jar = src/
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Custom
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.python.pydev.custom
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Fragment-Host: org.python.pydev;bundle-version="5.1.2"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Eclipse-PatchFragment: true
Bundle-ClassPath: library.jar,
 .
Require-Bundle: org.python.pydev.debug;bundle-version="5.5.0",
 org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core;bundle-version="8.0.0",
 org.apache.log4j
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse will build the library.jar rather than putting the class files in the normal place when the `build.properties` file looks like:

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               library.jar
source.library.jar = src/
```

The `library.jar` entry in the `bin.includes` replaces the normal `.` entry.

The `source.library.jar` entry says that the Java files in the `src` directly should be put in the `library.jar`.

The `Bundle-Classpath` entry in your MANIFEST.MF should be:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: library.jar
```

(so no '.' entry)

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I have in build.properties. There is a warning on the bin.includes entry that says: The plug-in's classpath library '.' does not have a corresponding source build entry. Is that a red herring? My .classpath is configured the same as other projects, where this warning doesn't appear. Is it different here because it's a fragment? I followed instructions here (http://blog.ankursharma.org/2009/11/source-and-output.html) to no avail.

Comment: I also tried many things in build.properties, such as "output.library.jar = .".  Then it complains: / is not an output folder. But I thought I was telling it to make that an output folder.

Comment: You probably need to set the Bundle-Classpath correctly in the MANIFEST.MF - see updated answer

Comment: Removing the . entry in Bundle-ClassPath does make the warning in build.properties go away. But library.jar still does not appear when I build or clean the project in eclipse.

Comment: It will only appear in the plugin jar/directory when you build an RCP or export the plugin

Comment: Yep, that's what I've been seeing. I was hoping to not require other developers working on the RCP app to run a Maven build, since they generally just launch the app as a runtime workbench from the eclipse IDE. I wonder if there is a way to kick off a build for just the fragment and host plug-in from the eclipse UI, maybe with an ant script or something.

Comment: 'File > Export > Deployable plug-ins or fragments' will do the build.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Exporting the fragment with the PDE wizard builds library.jar and places it in the exported plugin, but I was hoping for a way to have it placed in the project directory, just as the maven build does. I guess that's not supported.